# Array For each loop

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I'm trying create a multi dimensional array with columns `$i` and `$j`.

The array hasn't got any data inside it but first i have created the array then plan to load it. I want an output of 0 - 0 1 - 1 2 - 2 etc up to 10; I've lost my way a bit and I'm struggling to get my preferred output.

```
  ****Create array****
 $times_table = array();
        for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++){
            $times_table[$i] = array();

        }

    *****trying to load the array********

        for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++){
             for($j = 0; $j <= 10; $j++){
                $times_table [$i] [$j] 




            }

        }

    ?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I undestood what you want, it simply looks like :

```
for($i = 0: $i <= 10; $i++)
{
    echo $times_table[$i][$i];
}
```

So you got results from  0-0 to 10-10.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample it would be an array with rows (i) and columns (j)

So think of it as a table like this with each row holding in the colums the value of its count (I am leaving out 0 here for no specific reason, but it would be included in the real code) :

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 - j
0  0 

1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10

2  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10    

3  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10

4  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10

5  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10

6  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10

7  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10

8  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10

9  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10

10 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
 |
 i
```

if you want your array to be like this you can achieve this by the following code:

```
//create array
$times_table = array();
        for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++){
            $times_table[$i] = array();

        }

    //setting values
       for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++){
             for($j = 0; $j <= 10; $j++){
                $times_table[$i][$j]=$j 




            }

        }

    ?>
```

note that you have to set a value by assigning it: 
`$times_table[$i][$j]=<value>`  while `<value>` can be whatever you want.